# MySQL Event Scheduler: Archive data older than 1 day

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-event

i have a table with the latest currency rates, and i created another table as archive for the currency rates, and i want to firstly insert all rows that are older than 1 month to the archive and then delete it from the latest currency rates table.

I have read about MySQL Event Scheduler which is like cron task from Unix. I was trying to create a Mysql Event Scheduler to do this task but i get a syntax error.

The code is this:

> CREATE EVENT archivate
> ON SCHEDULE  EVERY 1 DAY
> DO BEGIN
> INSERT
> INTO    latestrate_archive
> SELECT  *
> FROM    latest_rate
> WHERE   DATE(timestamp) < CURDATE();
> FOR UPDATE;

DELETE
FROM    latestrate
WHERE   DATE(timestamp) < CURDATE();
END

And after i execute this commands in phpmyadmin i get this errors:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Anyone any has any idea where i am getting wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the semicolon from CURDATE(); - you use the semicolon to end a SQL statement.

Comment: Still displays the same error.